# Re-create an image from binary in Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I'm working on creating an upload/download images feature in Node.js. So far there is the POST request which saves the image as binary in MongoDB and also a GET request which returns that image back. But I don't know how can I use that response, it is an array of numbers and don't know how to transform it.

Here is the Mongo Model:

**image.js**
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
const ImageItem = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String
  },
  value: {
    type: Buffer
  },
});

module.exports = Image = mongoose.model('image', ImageItem);
```

**the POST image** which creates an entry in DB:

```
const image = require('../models/image');
const user = require('../models/user');

const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname + new Date().toISOString());
  },
});


const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.post('/upload', upload.single('value'), (req, res, next) => {
    const newImage = new image({
      id: req.body.id,
      value: req.file.path,
    });
    newImage
      .save()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
          message: 'created succesfully',
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err,
        });
      });
  });
};
```

and the entry created in DB:

[image]

for getting the image I created a GET request:

const image = require('../models/image');

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get('/upload/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.body.id', req.params);
    image.find({ id: req.params.id }, function (err, results) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(`error: ${err}`);
      } else {
        res.send(results);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

which tested in Postman returns a JSON containing an array of numbers:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ebd1c112892f4230d2d4ab4",
        "id": "email123@test.com",
        "value": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                117,
                112,
                108,
                111,
                97,
                100,
                115,
                47,
                117,
                115,
                101,
                114,
                80,
                105,
                99,
                116,
                117,
                114,
                101,
                46,
                112,
                110,
                103,
                50,
                48,
                50,
                48,
                45,
                48,
                53,
                45,
                49,
                52,
                84,
                49,
                48,
                58,
                50,
                51,
                58,
                49,
                51,
                46,
                57,
                51,
                52,
                90
            ]
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

How can I use this data to get the actual image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Buffer` from that array.

```
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(row.value.data); // [117, 112, 108...]
```

In any case checking your `ImageItem` schema, `row.value` is going to be a `Buffer`.

Now all you need to do is set the correct `content-type` and respond the `Buffer` instead of the Mongoose schema, using `res.send`.

```
app.get('/upload/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.body.id', req.params);
    image.find({ id: req.params.id }, function (err, results) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(`error: ${err}`);
      } else {
        const [row] = results;
        res.header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        res.send(row.value);
      }
    });
});
```

If you don't know the `Content-Type` you can use `file-type` package to get it from the `Buffer`.

```
const { mime } = fileType(row.value)
```

---

Since you're only getting a particular image you may want to use `.findOne` instead of `.find`

---

Now you have other issue, you're storing the file path, instead of the binary image which is what you want.

Those bytes you posted equals: `uploads/userPicture.png2020-05-14T10:23:13.934Z"`

```js
const data = new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array([117,112,108,111,97,100,115,47,117,115,101,114,80,105,99,116,117,114,101,46,112,110,103,50,48,50,48,45,48,53,45,49,52,84,49,48,58,50,51,58,49,51,46,57,51,52]))

console.log(data);
```

You have to save the actual image, not the file path for your code to work.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
// ....

const newImage = new image({
      id: req.body.id,
      value: await fs.readFile(req.file.path)
});
```

Comment: where should `const image` from first line should be put?

Comment: renamed it to `imageBuffer` to avoid conflicts. It's placed on the route as you can see on the second snippet.

Comment: First of all thank you for your response but it is not working at the moment. I put that code and in Postman it returns this error message: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /upload/email122345@test.com from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNRESET).` .I'm running my app from both client and server with nodemon. After trying to GET the image the server crashes: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined`

Comment: and on the client side it says: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /upload/email122345@test.com from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).` I'm using 5000 on server and 3000 on client

Comment: then you're not passing an array to `BUffer.from`

Comment: make sure the value youre passing to `Buffer.from` is the array you displayed: `[117, 112, 108]`, from the JSON you posted is `.value.data` but it may be a different value on your end. So just pass the actual array and it'll work

Answer (score 1):

When you send your image to a client, mongoose calls the method "toJSON", by default the Buffer JSON object looks like you showed. You could overwrite the toJSON method for the mongoose scheme (here you find info - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON) and your server will return a base64 representation of you image instead.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
  data: {
    type: Buffer,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

imageSchema.set("toJSON", {
  virtuals: true,
  versionKey: false,
  transform: function (doc, ret) {
    const base64 = doc.data.toString("base64");
    ret.data = `data:image${doc.type};base64,${base64}`;

    return ret;
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Image", imageSchema);
```